# What are the conditions required for partial fraction decomposition

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Take for example $f(x)=\frac{3x}{(x+1)^2}$ which breaks into $3x = A(x+1) + B(x+1)$ which can be further simplified into $3x = (A+B)(x+1)$ and after plugging in an $x$ value of $-1$ gives the statement $-3=0$. What is the error in this decomposition that gives this false statement? and in general, what is required to perform a partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: You can't have that decomposition. $A+B=3$ and $A+B=0$ are incompatible

Comment: The decomposition should be $\frac{3x}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{(x+1)^2}$, not $\frac{3x}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{x+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{3x}{(x+1)^2}$

$A(x+1)+B=3x$

$Ax+(A+B)=3\implies A=3, B=-3$

Comment: thank you, however can this be generalized for having higher powers of factors in the denominator?

Comment: @Lucas All polynomials can be written as a product of at most second degree, meaning all fractions with a polynomial in denominator can be written in the form: $$\frac{P(x)}{(x-a)^n(x^2+bx+c)^m}=\frac{A_1}{x-a}+\frac{A_2}{(x-a)^2}+\dots+\frac{A_n}{(x-a)^n}+\frac{B_1x+C_1}{x^2+bx+c}+\dots+\frac{B_mx+C_m}{(x^2+bx+c)^m}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{3x}{(x+1)^2} \\ 
&= \frac{3x+3-3}{(x+1)^2} \\
&= \frac{(3x+3)-3}{(x+1)^2} \\
&= \frac{3x+3}{(x+1)^2} - \frac{3}{(x+1)^2} \\
&= \frac{3(x+1)}{(x+1)^2} - \frac{3}{(x+1)^2} \\
&= \frac{3}{x+1} - \frac{3}{(x+1)^2}.
\end{align}
$$

Now let's do this decomposition using partial fractions. For this, we put
$$
\frac{3x}{(x+1)^2} = \frac{a}{x+1} + \frac{b}{(x+1)^2}. \tag{1}
$$
Of course the above identity is to hold for all (permissible) $x$.

Now multiplying both sides of (1) by $(x+1)^2$, we get
$$
3x = a(x+1) +b,
$$
or, after collecting like powers of $x$ on the right-hand-side,
$$ 
3x = ax + (a+b). \tag{2}
$$
Now the polynomial on the right-hand-side of (2) is equal to the polynomial on the left-hand-side if and only if the coefficients of the corresponding powers of $x$ in these two polynomials are equal, that is, if and only if we have
$$
a = 3 \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad a+b = 0,
$$
which hold if and only if
$$
a = 3 \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad b = -3.
$$

Hence we again have
$$
\frac{3x}{(x+1)^2} = \frac{3}{x+1} + \frac{ -3}{(x+1)^2} = \frac{3}{x+1} - \frac{3}{(x+1)^2},
$$
as before.